# sphinx4 5alpha master package gradle Build fail in netbeans 8.0

Tags: netbeans, gradle, speech-recognition, sphinx4

I downloaded the sphinx4-master from [github](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4). when I try to build it gives me a run time exception at LiveRecognizerTest.java:53. and build fail.
here is my console output,

```
Executing: gradle build
    Arguments: [-c, E:\project temp dev\sphinx4-master\settings.gradle]

:sphinx4-data:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:sphinx4-data:processResources
:sphinx4-data:classes
:sphinx4-data:jar
:sphinx4-core:compileJava
:sphinx4-core:processResources
:sphinx4-core:classes
:sphinx4-core:jar
:sphinx4-data:javadoc UP-TO-DATE
:sphinx4-core:javadoc
:sphinx4-core:javadocJar
:sphinx4-core:packageSources
:sphinx4-core:assemble
:sphinx4-core:compileTestJava
:sphinx4-core:processTestResources
:sphinx4-core:testClasses
:sphinx4-core:test

Gradle suite > Gradle test > edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveRecognizerTest.testGram FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at LiveRecognizerTest.java:53
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at LiveRecognizerTest.java:53

107 tests completed, 1 failed
:sphinx4-core:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sphinx4-core:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///E:/project%20temp%20dev/sphinx4-master/sphinx4-core/build/reports/tests/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4 mins 36.326 secs



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle build
```

I previously got an problem with building my application. here the [link](https://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/discussion/sphinx4/thread/d7eb30d2/?limit=25#cfbb) for problem. can someone help me to fix this two errors.

Comment: You seem to modify sphinx4 sources before running the build. You need to revert the changes you have made and make your changes outside of sphinx4.

Comment: yes. I downloaded the sphinx4 from github again and it was compiled.